# Is there any way to find chi-square of two different data sets on xmgrace

Tags: xmgrace

Is there any way to find the chi-square of two different datasets (actual and expected) on xmgrace instead of using excel datasheets?

Data Set 1:

```
 8.0    12.2
12.13   35.4
13.33   43.5
13.4    42.9
13.52   44.0
13.69   44.1
13.88   45.4
14.01   45.1
14.09   44.5
14.31   48.0
14.5    46.4
14.68   45.0
14.81   44.9
14.93   44.4
```

Data Set 2:

```
8 5.88968
9 7.67970
10 10.03960
11 13.25610
12 17.25480
13 21.68780
14 25.69500
15 28.84320
```

Comment: Do you have an example of the datasets and what is the desired output?

Comment: I just added two data sets. One is the expected, the other is the actual data. What I like to know is the chi-square of these.

Comment: How do you compute the chi square between datasets having different abscissas?

Comment: Once we find nth degree polynomial function with R=1, i think we can estimate the values  for the expected data at points where the actual data are.

Comment: An alternative free plotting tool that can calculate chi square values is veusz https://veusz.github.io/

Answer (score 0):

I don't think xmgrace is the right tool for the job. Having said that, you can still cook up something that works (although in a very cumbersome way). In your specific case:

1. load up both datasets in xmgrace so that set S0 is the actual data and S1 is the expected data.
2. open the "data -> transformations -> interpolation/splines" dialog
3. choose the "Akima spline" method, the "Abscissas of another set" for sampling and select the S1 set in the "sampling set" part of the dialog. Use "Apply". Now set S2 should contain the expected values associated to the abscissas of set S0.
4. open the "data -> transformations -> evaluate expression" dialog, select S0 and use the following formula: `y=(S0.y - S2.y)^2/S0.y`. Click "Apply". The new dataset S3 contains the single contributions of the chi-square value.
5. to sum them up select S3, deselect the set on the right-most column and use the formula `y=sum(y)`. The new S4 dataset contains your chi-square value.

Regarding your reply to my comment, you may want to first fit the expected values to a polynomial and then interpolate that dataset.

Comment: Your explanation is not as clear. Let's say s0 is the actual data and s1 is the expected data as you said. open the "data -> transformations -> interpolation/splines" dialog. So far so good! s0 will be set graph source and destination automatically and I will leave it that way, I guess. The method is Akima spline and sampling abscissas of another set. s1 will be selected as the sampling set, and then apply. Here comes the message " no source sets selected".  Step 4 in your list. Which one(s) will be selected as a source and destination?

Comment: @usermrt, maybe that depends on the OS you are using. When I open that dialog there are no sets selected. I have to manually set S0 as a source. As I said, do that, while leave the destination set unselected. Do the same for step n. 5. I have also updated the description for step n. 3: just select S1 in the "sampling set" part of the dialog